# A Chrome extension that displays a list of all open tabs

Tags: chrome

On Firefox, once you open a certain amount of tabs, a dropdown triangle icon shows up at the rightmost corner of the window to display a list of all open tabs, like this:

[image]

Is there an extension that adds a similar feature to Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb) extension,

Quick tabs list out all the open tabs just like firefox list.

> FEATURES
>
> - Lists all the open tabs in Chrome across all of your open windows
> - Tabs are listed in most recently used (MRU) order and excludes the current tab (since you're switching tabs)
> - Fuzzy search your bookmarks:
>
>   - Bookmarks are automatically searched when only a few tabs match your search string
>   - Add a space
>       at the start or end of your search string to search bookmarks along
>       with tabs...

Comment: Glad could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall) it's what you looking for.

From the website:

> **How it works:**
>   Whenever you find yourself with too many tabs, click the OneTab icon to convert all of your tabs into a list. When you need to access the tabs again, you can either restore them individually or all at once.
>   When your tabs are in the OneTab list, you will save up to 95% of memory because you will have reduced the number of tabs open in Google Chrome.

Comment: I have OneTab, and it closes all tabs before listing them, which is not what Firefox does (and what I want). I want all tabs to remain open and running.